# Covering a cube with ball without too much intersection

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry

I'm struggling with this problem that fell elementary, and probably it is.

Take $[0,1]^n$ and cover it with a bunch of open sets in such a way that taken $n+2$ sets their intersection is empty.

If we take small open cubes we can make a grid and moving them a little bit we obtain a configuration that covers $[0,1]^n$ without having more then $n+1$ intersecting cubes.

Can we do something similar with open balls of radius $r$?

Comment: The problem just says open sets and you say that can be done. Do you have a source for the idea it can be done with open balls, or is that just something you're curious about?

Comment: I don't understand: what is stopping you from covering $[0,1]^n$ with *one* open set, namely $(-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon)^n$ for some small $\epsilon>0$? Is there a restriction how many open sets need to be in the "bunch"?

Comment: The radius $r$ is fixed and can be taken arbitrarily small!

Comment: I don't know if it can be done with open balls. There is a definition of topological dimension that say that if every open cover as a refinement with no more than $n+1$ intersecting set then the dimension is $\le n$. From the cubic covering it follows that $dim([0,1]^n)\le n $ indeed to have a refinement you can just take cubes of size less then the lebesgue number of the cover. To my understanding however it is not clear from dimension theory if we can make a cover with balls.